# How to handle JSON response from Vimeo API when the video id that was requested doesn't match up to a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, video, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have this section of code that requests a video from the Vimeo API and it works whenever the `video_id` is a valid id, however if i have an invalid Id i receive an internal server error. I know my code is breaking in this section. I believe I just don't know how to read the JSON response that i'm getting from the API.

Below is my code, as well as the JSON response I receive when I request a video with an invalid id using the terminal.

```
VIMEO_REGEX = %r{(?:vimeo?\.com\/(\d+))}
    def video_id
      self.class.search_params(metadata)
    end

    def self.search_params(metadata)
      return unless metadata && metadata[:url]
      match_data = metadata[:url].match(VIMEO_REGEX)
      match_data.try(:[], 1)
    end

    def self.metadata_fields
      [:url]
    end

    protected

    def validate_metadata_url
      return unless errors.empty?
      errors .add :metadata, 'url is not a valid vimeo url' unless metadata[:url].match(VIMEO_REGEX)
    end

    def validate_api_payload
      validate_metadata_url
      return unless errors.empty?
      metadata[:payload] = JSON.parse RestClient.get(
        "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/#{video_id}",
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ##################')
      errors.add :metadata, 'resource not found' if metadata[:payload][:errors]
    end
```

the section of code that i'm looking at is the validate_api_payload, the rest of that code is just for context.

JSON response :

```
`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" https://api.vimeo.com/videos/21011831o
```

{
    "error": "The requested video could not be found"
} `

why can't my code handle this response?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Note the video id `21011831o`, the last character is the letter o. Vimeo video uris and video ids will always be numerical.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of that. I know the video ID is not valid, i did that for testing purposes. I want to be able to handle incorrect ID's being entered by the user.

Comment: Understood, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is working correct. If a video ID isn't valid, the Vimeo API will return a `404` status code, with `"The requested video could not be found"` in the body just as you described.

I think you're mistaking that 404 as an "Internal service error". If the API had an internal service error, you'd see a 500/5xx error.

Note that the API may also return a `403 Forbidden` error if you don't have permission to access the video (private video, etc.)

More info here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos

Comment: Thanks @Tommy. That makes sense. I do have 500, not a 404, but I know why that is and that doesn't matter. I just have one more question. As you can see have the `metadata[:payload]` is receiving the JSON response. Problem is when I do get a 404, the code breaks there. How do I handle/receive this 404 so it doesn't crash the app?  The metadata is defined as a hash in a parent file

Comment: We would like to clean up any 500's you encounter. Please send vimeo any details you have so we can fix them!